# How to clear all memcache in app engine. Java environment

Tags: java, google-app-engine, memcached

I need to clear it all to make the data become clean, is there any API I can use?

Comment: what data you are talking about exactly ?

Comment: Are you talking about using the MemcacheService in Google App Engine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a [clearAll](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/memcache/MemcacheService.html#clearAll()) method on the MemcacheService object.

Comment: Alternatively, if your using the JCache API (as described in http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/memcache/usingjcache.html), try using "clear" on the Cache object.

I am guessing it invokes clearAll on the underlying low level service object